# Changing the color of an image link on hover

Tags: css

I have an image that is a link:

My HTML looks like:

```
       <div class="imgholder">
         <a href="#" title="Home" class="imglink"><img src="/images/img1.JPG" alt="Image"  class="img-responsive" id="electricone"> </a>

           <div class="item1">
             <h1 class="slickfont1">Home</h1>
           </div>       
       </div>
```

I know this seems like a simple question, but what is the ***best*** way to style the image link so that it becomes darker when you :hover?

Is it best to do an li around the link and style that with li:hover? Or is it best to style the actual div *or* actual link? What would my css look like?

Comment: You want to make the image itself darker? You're best to use `a:hover`, as antique versions of IE don't work with `:hover` on non-`a` elements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m8V2p/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a background color to your `A` element,
than on `.imglink:hover img{  }` handle the image opacity

An example would be:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nabad/1/edit)**

```
a.imglink{
  background:         #000;
  display:            inline-block;
}
a.imglink img{
  vertical-align:     middle;
  transition:         opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
a.imglink:hover img{
  opacity:            0.5;
}
```

Comment: This finally worked, Display:inline-block was the key. Thanks!

Comment: @TarDavis I thought I had to show you ;) you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Use pseudo classes

```
.imglink { normal styling }
.imglink:hover { background-color: (change background color); color: (change font color) }
```

If you want to change the image itself you will either need to set it as a background image and swap it out or use jquery to change the src

Comment: you may want to readup on CSS then and pseudo classes http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: @user934902 Please don't suggest links to w3schools, they've done  (and they still do) enough harm to the programming community providing poor or inaccurate specifications. Rather take a look on a community-cared documentation like MDN

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<div class="imgholder">
  <a href="#" title="Home" class="imglink">
    <img src="http://www.cancer-fund.org/images/share/diy/img_sample.gif" alt="Image"  class="img-responsive" id="electricone">
   </a>

        <div class="item1">
             <h1 class="slickfont1">Home</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSs**

```
.imglink

{
   background-color:blue; 
}
.imglink:hover
{
    background-color:red;
 }

.imglink:hover .img-responsive
{
    opacity:0.4;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m8V2p/5/)

Comment: Hi @Amarnath any idea why mine would not be working: #electricone {
width:100%;
height:366px;

}


.imglink {
background-color:blue;
}