# Image shade change when hovering not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the image to turn slightly reddish when hovering over. I've managed to get the opacity to change from 0.8 to 1.0, and zoom in slightly when hovering, but I don't know why the image isn't turning slightly red. The code that is failing is:

```
background-color: rgba(110,0,0,.5);
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here? Appreciate any help, thanks

```css
.subsection-parent{
 width:286px;
 height:auto;
 margin-right:51px;
 float:left;
}
.subsection-big-brother{
 width:282px;
 height:282px;
 border:2px solid #2778BA;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}
.subsection-child{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity:0.8;
}
.subsection-child:hover {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
 opacity: 1;
 /* GROW! */
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
  /* The below does not work */
  background-color: rgba(110,0,0,.5);
}
.elephant{
 background:url(http://cdn.publishyourarticles.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/elephants-9a.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="subsection-parent">
<a href="#">
<div class="subsection-big-brother">
<div class="subsection-child elephant"></div>
</div>
<h3>H3 Text</h3></a>
</div>
```

Comment: your trying to change a background colour but it's not the background colour you're seeing, because it's an image it doesn't show a background (unless the image has transparant areas). Instead you should change the colour of a layer on top of the image.

Comment: [Read this answer to a similar question and apply it to your situation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21692839/3536236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

Give `.subsection-big-brother` a background-color. Set the opacity to 0. Add a transition property here too.

```
.subsection-big-brother {
  background-color: rgba(110, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: .4s;
}
```

When you hover over `.subsection-big-brother` change the opacity to 1 - essentially turning that div red.

```
.subsection-big-brother:hover {
  background-color: rgba(110, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

You can decide how much of the image you want to see on top of this by adjusting the opacity of `.subsection-child` on hover.

```
.subsection-child:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```css
.subsection-parent {
  width: 286px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 51px;
  float: left;
}
.subsection-big-brother {
  width: 282px;
  height: 282px;
  border: 2px solid #2778BA;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(110, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: .4s;
}
.subsection-big-brother:hover {
  background-color: rgba(110, 0, 0, 1);
}
.subsection-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: .4s;
}
.subsection-child:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  /* GROW! */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /* The below does not work */
}
.elephant {
  background: url(http://cdn.publishyourarticles.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/elephants-9a.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="subsection-parent">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="subsection-big-brother">
      <div class="subsection-child elephant"></div>
    </div>
    <h3>H3 Text</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `background-color` is for the `background-image` which already in full size width/height. Use a pseudo element or another html element as the background-color,

here's an example

```css
.subsection-parent {
  width: 286px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 51px;
  float: left;
}
.subsection-big-brother {
  width: 282px;
  height: 282px;
  border: 2px solid #2778BA;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.subsection-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* EXAMPLE */
.subsection-child:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* The below does not work */
  background-color: rgba(110, 0, 0, .5);
}
.subsection-child:hover {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  opacity: 1;
  /* GROW! */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.elephant {
  background: url(http://cdn.publishyourarticles.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/elephants-9a.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="subsection-parent">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="subsection-big-brother">
      <div class="subsection-child elephant"></div>
    </div>
    <h3>H3 Text</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```